# variables by default in airflow and BigQueryToGCSOperator

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have an airflow DAG with the following task.
At runtime, there is an error because there are special characters in the job_id.
How can I correctly pass the variables to the task definition?

```
date='{{ ds }}'
job_id=date+'{{ ts }}'
inst_dag_id="name_dag"
DAG(dag_id=inst_dag_id,
          default_args = default_args,
          catchup = False,  
          max_active_runs = 6,
          schedule_interval = scheduler_reports[report] ) as dag: #HORA UTC-0

      export_audits_to_gcs = bigquery_to_gcs.BigQueryToGCSOperator(
                task_id='export_audits_to_gcs',
                gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
                compression="GZIP",
                source_project_dataset_table=bq_destination_table_name,
                destination_cloud_storage_uris=[output_file],
                field_delimiter=";",
                export_format='CSV',
                job_id=inst_dag_id+job_id
            )
```

the mistake is :
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 POST https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/name_proyect/jobs?prettyPrint=false: Invalid job ID "name_dag{{ ds }}{{ ts }}_6c6c293aa2fa1a63fadeaecefe7ff58c". Job IDs must be alphanumeric (plus underscores and dashes) and must be at most 1024 characters long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I raised [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/30006) to address this.

For [`apache-airflow-providers-google>8.11.0`](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-google/):

Your code will work as the PR included in the release.

For [`apache-airflow-providers-google<=8.11.0`](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-google/):

This happens because `job_id` is not in [template_fields](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/464ab1b7caa78637975008fcbb049d5b52a8b005/airflow/providers/google/cloud/transfers/bigquery_to_gcs.py#L90-L96).

If you can not update provider to newer version you can create custom operator to address it:

```
class MyBigQueryToGCSOperator(BigQueryToGCSOperator):

    template_fields = (
        "job_id",
    ) + BigQueryToGCSOperator.template_fields
```

Then replace the class in your code:

```
  export_audits_to_gcs = MyBigQueryToGCSOperator(
            task_id='export_audits_to_gcs',
            gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
            compression="GZIP",
            source_project_dataset_table=bq_destination_table_name,
            destination_cloud_storage_uris=[output_file],
            field_delimiter=";",
            export_format='CSV',
            job_id=inst_dag_id+job_id
        )
```